# PHP $_SESSION is inconsistent while authentication

Tags: javascript, php, session

I am trying to build an authentication system into my php website. I have no experiences with it so I go by documentation. No Frameworks or anything. Just plain vanilla PHP with a XAMPP Tech Stack on Windows.

1. I check on my index.php at the beginning if the Session is already running. If not, create one with a dedicated Session Name, since I have several web services on my Apache and they shouldnt interfere with eachother.
2. Then start the session if none is there.
3. Check if $_SESSION["loggedin" => true]. If yes, give me the content of the website. If not, display a login window
4. After authentication in the login window, the website should redirect to the index.php, so the initialized $_SESSION will be validated again where $_SESSION['loggedin' => true] and the content will be visible.

**1. Problem: index.php**

At any time when the index.php is checking the session, the session is not existent. And if php initializes it, it is filled like that $_SESSION["loggedin" => false];. After the authentication it is supposed to be true. And before authentication $_SESSION["loggedin"]  it shouldnt be set at all since this step is only performed a few lines below.

**2. Problem: The Controller post_login.php**

After I start the session, the session is already authenticated with $_SESSION["logged => true, "user" => "KENNUNG"];
How is it possible that index.php and post_login.php are handling different sessions? Or at least different session states?

The code is as follows:

**/index.php**

```
<?php

include_once("Config/settings.php"); //Some config values like $appName

if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_name($appName);
    session_start([
        'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
        //'cookie_domain' => $actual_link,
        'gc_maxlifetime'  => 86400,
        'use_cookies' => 1,
        'use_only_cookies' => 1
    ]);
}
// $_SESSION is already $_SESSION['loggedin' => false] at this point (?)

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ROOT = __DIR__;
$content = "";

if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == 1) {
    $content = $ROOT . "/View/Authentication/content.php";
} else {
    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;
    $_REQUEST = array();
    $content = $ROOT . "/View/Authentication/login.php";
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <title><?php $appName ?></title>
    <base href="" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="Assets/lib/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="nav-bar" id="nav-bar">
    <?php include($ROOT . "/View/Nav/nav.php"); ?>
</div>
<?php require($content); ?>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**/View/Authentication/login.php**

```
<?php
include_once(__DIR__ . "/../../Config/settings.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_name($appName);
    session_start();
}

?>
<script src="View/Authentication/login.js" type="module"></script>
<style>
    @import url("./View/Authentication/login.css") screen;
</style>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="LoginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="LoginModalLabel">Login</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="login-form">
                    <label class="form-label" for="user_id">User ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id">

                    <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**/View/Authentication/login.js**

```
//@Stackoverflow: Ignore Modal Initialization
openLoginModal();
function openLoginModal() {
    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance('#LoginModal', {
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    modal.show();

    $("#login-form").on('submit', (event)=> {
        event.preventDefault();
        postAuthentication(event);
    });
}

function postAuthentication(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    const entries = $(event.currentTarget).serializeArray();

    for (const entry of entries) {
        formData.append(entry.name, entry.value);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/mydomain/Controller/Auth/post_login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: (response) => {
            window.location = "index.php"
        },
        error: (response) => {
            alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**/Controller/Authentication/post_login.php**

```
<?php
include_once("Config/settings.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_name($appName);
    session_start();
}


include_once(__DIR__ . "/../../Service/AuthenticationService.php");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "POST") {

    throw new \Exception('Wrong method');
}
elseif (!isset($_POST['user_id'])|| !isset($_POST['password']) || empty(trim($_POST['user_id']))|| empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
    throw new \Exception('Please fill out all input fields!');
} elseif (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {
    throw new \Exception('Password needs 8 figures!');
}

$return = $authenticationService->authenticate($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['password']);
header('Location: ../../index.php', true);
echo json_encode($return);
```

**/Service/AuthenticationService.php **

```
<?php
include_once("Config/settings.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_name($appName);
    session_start();
}

require_once(__DIR__ . "./../Data/UserRepository.php");

class AuthenticationService
{
    private UserRepository $userRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    public function authenticate(string $kennung, string $password): array
    {

        $user = strtoupper(trim($kennung));
        $PW = hash('sha3-512', trim($password));

        $returnData = [
            'loginOk' => false,
            'passwordOk' => false,
            'user' => $user
        ];

        $user = $this->userRepository->get($user);
        $dbPW = $user['password'];

        if ($dbPW == $PW) {

            $returnData['loginOk']    = true;
            $returnData['passwordOk'] = true;
            $returnData['$user'] = $user;

            //Password is correct, so start a new session
            //Store data in session variables
            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
        }
        return $returnData;
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, I would advise not to invent your own password hashing mechanism. Learn about PHP's built-in [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) functionality instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords).

Comment: `If not, create one with a dedicated Session Name, since I have several web services on my Apache and they shouldnt interfere with eachother.`...they shouldn't anyway. I would be very surprised if this actually caused an issue. Did you experience a real issue, or just assume it? Just try without using this, and see if it helps your issue.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a JS problem?

Comment: In your index.php, you start the session with a specific set of parameters - whereas in the other two scripts, you have left those out, so that it will use the default value from the configuration there. That potential discrepancy could easily be problematic. You should probably put this into an include file as well, rather than writing the same thing _differently_ in multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it seems like you check for sessions before running `sessiont_start()`. That won't work.

The `$_SESSION` superglobal will not be populated until you've started the session. Additionally, without having the session started, you cannot save session information.

I would assume that fixing the order of starting the session and accessing the `$_SESSION` superglobal would fix both your issues.

Additionally, you're starting sessions with different configurations in `index.php` compared to your controller scripts. Without having tested this, I could imagine this could pose an issue in some contexts.

Try and slim down your initial attempt and start sessions before accessing them, don't name your session initially and don't use specific/different session configurations until you have a working proof of concept.